# Update column value laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update  a column value to approve a service ( changing the value from 0 to 1 )
and I'm getting an error :

**Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message**

This is the Controller :

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Session;
    use App\Service;

    class ServiceController extends Controller{

      public function approuver($id){

          Service::where([
             'id' => $id,
          ])->update(array('flag'=>1));

          $request->session()->flash('notif','Mise à jour reussi!');

          return back();
     }
 }
```

This is the route:

```
 Route::post('/Services/approuver/{id}', 'ServiceController@approuver');
```

This is the blade file :

```
<div id="modal1{{$service->id}}" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">

<p>Voulez vous vraiment approuver ce service ?</p>

 <div class="row">                                
  <form class="col s12"   method="post" 
  action="/Services/approuver/{{$service->id}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
      @method('PUT')


       <span>   <input type="submit" class="btn purple hoverable waves 
      effect" value="Oui"></span>
     <span>    <a href="#" class="btn red hoverable waves effect modal- 
     action modal-close" id="Non"> Non</a></span>



   </form> 
   </div>                     

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a PUT request but in your route you used POST method
do like this in your route

```
Route::put('/Services/approuver/{id}', 'ServiceController@approuver');
```

Comment: I changed it ,it takes me to another page but nothing happened!

Answer (score 0):

Your route is defined as `POST` but your form has `@method('PUT')`. You have to decide which one you want to use.

Comment: I changed it ,it takes me to another page but nothing happened!

Comment: That's different issue but I think controller method signature should be `public function approuver($request, $id)`? Anyway, I dont understand why it wouldnt complain about undefined variable `$request`.

Comment: Do like this public function anyfunction(Request $request)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `@method('PUT')` or change defined route like this.

`Route::put('/Services/approuver/{id}', 'ServiceController@approuver');`